# RadComboBox OnClientItemsRequested not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

Is there anything about my code below that would prevent the client event "OnClientItemsRequested" from firing?  I have a couple RadComboBox elements on a page that sometimes get into a state where they load nothing and don't fire the "OnClientItemsRequested" event.  Is there anything I could do to FORCE this event to fire?

```
<telerik:RadComboBox 
  ID="SomeFilter" 
  runat="server" 
  Height="230px" Width="300px" style="margin-bottom:5px" 
  DropDownWidth="298px" 
  EmptyMessage="Choose..." 
  HighlightTemplatedItems="true" 
  EnableLoadOnDemand="true" 
  EnableVirtualScrolling="true" 
  ItemRequestTimeout="500" 
  ShowMoreResultsBox="True" 
  OnClientSelectedIndexChanging="OnClientSelectedIndexChanging"
  OnClientDropDownClosing="OnClientDropDownClosing" 
  OnClientBlur="OnClientBlur" 
  OnItemsRequested="TaskEmployeesFilter_ItemsRequested" 
  OnClientItemsRequested="OnClientItemsRequested"
  EnableItemCaching="false">
  <ItemTemplate>
    ...
  </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you binding it to data?  You can invoke the event by calling the method: requestItems(), which this method makes the request from the client to the server.

See more about it here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/combobox/combo_client_model.html

Are you binding via web service, or another way?

HTH.

Comment: Manually, in the server ItemsRequested event handler.  I am getting into states where neither the client nor the server ItemsRequested evetns are being fired.

Comment: Interesting, try manually invoking requestItems(); this worked for me as it called my server-side web service.

Comment: Plus, try without the ItemTemplate; I don't know if item templates are supported with client-side binding.

Answer (score 1):

You might want the onClientItemsRequesting rather than onClientItemsRequested. Fires before the load on demand post back, hitting after might be killing your event.